# Authenticated Referrals Not Displaying in OAuth Dialog

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, oauth, server-side

I am having trouble getting the user will see the dialogue of acceptance of "Authenticated Referrals".

In the configuration of the app, in a section of Auth Dialog, and marked the license (in User Permissions & Friend) in this case to allow access to email, but testing in the dialogue only appears "The App will receive: Your basic data. ".

Can you help me and tell someone how I can implement it for me to leave these permits?

Thank you very much.

PS> Sorry for my English.

Comment: Thanks to those who have taken an interest, I've found a solution that someone else might you be interested in:

Instead of redirecting the user to "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id = ...." I have sent to "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id = ..." and now if I get the permit application and the server receives the necessary data.

I hope someone will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who have taken an interest, I've found a solution that someone else might you be interested in: Instead of redirecting the user to "facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id = ...." I have sent to "facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id = ..." and now if I get the permit application and the server receives the necessary data. I hope someone will be useful.